# When does a BackboneJS ModelView get garbage collected in this case?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a ListView and InstanceView defined in my Backbone code. The ListView is associated with a collection and it instantiates an InstanceView like so

```
render: function () {
   this.collection.forEach(function(instance){
       var commentHTML = new InstanceView({
         model: instance
       }).render();
       renderedComments.push(commentHTML);
   });
}
```

The new view instance goes out of scope after the render call finishes.  What I've noticed is that the view persists in memory, though. I can tell because the events attached to it still fire long after the render method terminates.

So, does the view avoid gc because of its reference to the model object which, in turn, is referenced by the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the view is created events are registered on the model. The callbacks have references to the view, preventing it from being gc'ed.

Check out the backbone code on [github](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js). The events are hooked up in the `delegateEvents`method.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are garbage collected whenever the JS engine feels like collecting them.

Your question, however, is actually different.

Just because *you* cannot access an object does not mean:

1. *Nothing* can, and
2. Things it attaches *also* go away.

Also, you *explicitly* add the object to collection, so it's not eligible for collection.